# Fill a char array with int values

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using a library for an Arduino project that has a function I need to call. This function accepts just one parameter of type `const char*`. Let's call it **foo**.

I need to pass some `int` values to **foo**, so I convert them first using `sprintf`. So far so good.

The problem comes when I try to fill an array with `int` values converted to `char` and then call **foo** with each of the values in the array.

I hope this explains the problem better:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


// This function cannot be modified because
// is a part of a library
void foo(const char *bar){
    cout << "Result: " << bar << endl;
}

int main() {
    char *values[10]; // My array of values
    char tmp[10]; // Temporary buffer for the int > char conversion

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int samplevalue = i * 2; // Just a sample value, not important
        sprintf(tmp, "%d", samplevalue); // Copy the sample value to the temporary buffer
        values[i] = tmp; // Assign the value of the temp var to a position in my values array
        cout << values[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "==============" << endl;


    // Here comes the problem:
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        foo(values[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that code is the following:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
==============
Result: 18
Result: 18
Result: 18
Result: 18
Result: 18
Result: 18
Result: 18
Result: 18
Result: 18
Result: 18
```

As you can see, all of the **Result** lines are equal to the last value assigned to the `tmp` var. I guess it's because each of the values in the `values[10]` array contains a pointer to the tmp variable instead of its actual value.

What I'd like to have is a different number on each **Result** line, as in the first `for` loop.

I guess it's pretty obvious that I'm not even near to be a C++ expert and any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You only have one `tmp` so why would you expect multiple values?

Comment: Since this is tagged as [tag:arduino] does that mean you do not have access to `std::sting` and `std::to_string()`?

Comment: Are you expecting (char*)values[10] or char (*values[10]),
Make sure you use brackets to specify which kind are you trying to use.

Comment: All Values storing the same address to tmp. Which value is 18 in the end

Comment: First of all I don't get why all the negative votes. If I'm here is because I don't understand something and I need help.
@stark I come from JavaScript and Python, where there are no pointers and one `tmp` could be changed to a different value each time. I know this is possible in C++, but I'm missing something.

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan The library I'm using expects a `const char *`, so what I need is to store strings that could be accepted by that function.

Comment: This doesn't look like Arduino code to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I finally got to get it working. In Arduino strings are declared as `String variable;`, and the `c_str()` function converts a string into a `const char *`, so I convert the `int` number to `String`, and then to `const char *`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    String tmp = String(i * 2);
    values[i] = tmp.c_str();
}
```

And that's it! It works now :)

Comment: That's wrong, `values[i]` will be a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A `char *` pointer and an array are not a string. Use `std::string` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


// This function cannot be modified because
// is a part of a library
void foo(const char *bar)
{
    cout << "Result: " << bar << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string values[10]; // My array of values
    char tmp[10]; // Temporary buffer for the int > char conversion

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int samplevalue = i * 2; // Just a sample value, not important
        sprintf(tmp, "%d", samplevalue); // Copy the sample value to the temporary buffer
        values[i] = tmp; // Assign the value of the temp var to a position in my values array
        cout << values[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "==============" << endl;


    // Here comes the problem:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        foo(values[i].c_str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When using an array, all the pointers in your `values` array point to `tmp`, you can check that by looping through `values` and printing the address like this

```
fprintf(stdout, "%p\n", values[i]);
```

So because you `sprintf()` into `tmp` all the values, the value that will be printed is always the last one, there is no copy implied in

```
values[i] = tmp;
```

that just makes `values[i]` point to `tmp`, so when you access `values[i]` you really access `tmp`.

With `std::string` copy occurs.

Also, you should probably use a string stream to write numbers into each `values[i]` directly, because `sprintf()` is very dangerous.

Or even better use a real c++ solution like this one,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

// This function cannot be modified because
// is a part of a library
void foo(const char *bar)
{
    std::cout << "Result: " << bar << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        values.push_back(std::to_string(2 * i));
        std::cout << values[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "==============" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        foo(values[i].c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that now, you can change the number of elements in `values` and you can use it as an array if you need to, just read the documentation for `std::vector`.

Comment: You also need to change `foo(values[i]);` is `values` is an array of `std::string`s.

Comment: Do note that the OP cannot change the function that takes a `const char*`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Noted!

Comment: Thanks for your help, @IharobAlAsimi !
The problem is that since it's an Arduino project, I can't use `std::string` (sorry, I just used the Arduino tag, but I forgot to mention it in the question description). 
I tried replacing `std::string` with `String`, which is how Arduino declares strings, but I get an error:
`error: no matching function for call to 'foo(int, int, 
String&)'`
It's because the last parameter should be a `const char *`